# twist or untwist object in increments

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate a DNA being untwisted as an enzyme moves across it and I can't get it to look the way I want. Here's what I've tried so far:

If I use the Simple Deform modifier, either the whole thing is twisted or nothing at all. If I use shorter increments of DNA with this modifier, the ends are not attached to each other and spin independently of each other.

If I use Shapekeys, the DNA doesn't untwist so much as it deforms (since the vertices move linearly to their destination points).

I have an idea that it might work using hooks but I have no idea how (I'm rather new to Blender). Help would be much appreciated, I'm also happy with a link to a tutorial doing something kind of like that.

Comment: I'd use an armature for this.